# Extract Specific JSON Object and Display Them Independently

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have data that looks like this

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "data1": {
            "serialNumber": "abc123",
            "version": "1.6"
        },
        "data2": {
            "irrelvent": [
                "irrelvent",
                "irrelvent"
            ]
        },
        "data3": {
            "irrelevantLibs": {
                "irrelevantFiles": [
                    "irrelevant.jar",
                    "irrelevant.jar",
                    "irrelevant.jar"
                ]
            }
        },
        "data4": {
            "configuration": "auth"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the Jackson JSON Processor. What I need to do under the `data` object is to extract each `data(x)` into it's own data.

Hard to explain but I will try to be detailed. My intent is to make the JSON data more readable for our customers. So I'm trying to make the JSON data more friendly by splitting each `data(x)` object into blocks/tables on a website. So `data1` will be displayed independently. Then `data2` will be displayed independently and so on. So in this case I have four `data(x)` objects and I want to store those four objects into four different `Strings` and display them however I want. My problem is how do I get the Jackson Processor to do this?

Not sure if this is helpful but my current JSON function to process the JSON data is this:

```
public static String stringify(Object o) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
        printer.indentArraysWith(new Lf2SpacesIndenter());
        return mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(o);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm positive that I can manipulate the processor to get those data separated but I don't know where to start.

EDIT: Hmm, since Jackson seems to be a pretty difficult parser to work with, would it be easier if I used the Javascript JSON parser to extract only the `data` objects? Since I already have Jackson convert the JSON data into a String, using Javascript would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out after really digging into the documentation. I had to use `JsonNode` in order to extract what I wanted. Note that the variable `appName` is just there for me to easily display the string `data(x)` while `iteNode` is just all elements under `data(x)`

```
public static List<String> jsonSplit(String o) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
    printer.indentArraysWith(new Lf2SpacesIndenter());

    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(o, JsonNode.class); 
    Iterator<String> appName = rootNode.get("data").getFieldNames();
    Iterator<JsonNode> iteNode = rootNode.get("data").getElements();

    while (iteNode.hasNext()){
        list.add(appName.next());
        list.add(mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(iteNode.next()));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Hmm, since Jackson seems to be a pretty difficult parser to work with, would it be easier if I used the Javascript JSON parser to extract only the data objects?"

Seeing as you are working with Java have you considered using Sling? http://sling.apache.org/ It is an external library which will allow you parser and explore JSON data structures quite swiftly, and most of all cleanly.